# Early 2011 Macbook Pro DisplayPort 1.2 driver

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, displayport

So I searched a bunch, lots of threads on this, but unfortunately either they haven't been resolved, or its not helpful.

I have a Macbook Pro (early 2011) model w/ the Intel Core i5. It is currently running OS X Version 10.9.5, and I just recently purchased a second monitor for it ([Dell P2014H](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&cs=19&l=en&sku=320-9798)). I am using a [Mini DisplayPort to Display port cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7RJQPY) to connect this monitor to the laptop, and it is working.

However, the Macbook is restricting the resolution to 1360x768, it's not using the 1600x900 that I would like. If you set it to that resolution, the 2nd monitor blacks out, and goes to sleep. After a lot of troubleshooting (resetting PRAM, SMC...), I borrowed a Mini DisplayPort to VGA adapter from a friend, and I tried that. That worked with the proper resolution, no problems.

Now, I am guessing that this is occurring because of DisplayPort 1.2 that the monitor uses, and the macbook does not work with that. Unfortunately Dell does not make a driver for OSX. I could also not find any drivers online. Does anyone have/know where I can find a driver, or know another method I can use to fix this resolution issue (other than buying a vga or dvi adapter)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated to OSX Yosemite, was hoping that would do something, but still have same issue...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar compatibility issue a few years back with a Dell monitor.  After a replacement and multiple support calls, it ended up being the Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.  The embedded chip didn't send the proper info the Dell monitor is expecting.

After I replaced the Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable with a [Mini DisplayPort to DisplayPort adapter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002YQYCUM) and a normal sized DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable, it worked properly.

There is some kind of incompatibility with Dell monitors and MDP to DP cables.  I've used the MDP to DP cable with other monitors without problems but have only had success with Dells when using a MDP to DP Adapter with a DP-DP cable.

Hope this helps!